# Call python-nmap PortScanner(), nmap not found

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, nmap, sys

In my virtualenv I installed python-nmap and nmap is installed (OS X).
But if I call mmap like (virtualenv activated...):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/bin')

import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

I get the following error:

> Raise PortScannerError('nmap program was not found in path')
>
> nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path'

Is there still another way to enter the path to nmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) governs where the Python interpreter looks for importing modules. The "path" in your error is the OS's `PATH` environment variable, which tells the OS where to look for `Nmap`. You can either set this directly with [`os.putenv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.putenv) or you can pass the full path to the `nmap` binary in the `nmap.PortScanner` constructor:

```
nm = nmap.PortScanner('/usr/local/bin/nmap')
```

Comment: nm = nmap.PortScanner('/usr/local/bin/nmap') returns: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @user2883656 I may have been looking at a newer version of the python-nmap package which supported this syntax.

Comment: Which version you use? I use 0.1.4, because 0.3.3 only support Python 3. But I change the project to Python 3 and will report.

Comment: @user2883656 If you need to support python 2, you may want to check out https://github.com/savon-noir/python-libnmap (not an endorsement, I haven't used it)

Answer (score 1):

Portet the project to Python 3 and update nmap to 0.3.3 now it works.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

install nmap with homebrew

```
brew install nmap
```

Then your install will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried these methods but not worked then I further looked into it.

Error:

```
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nmap/nmap.py", line 137, in __init__
raise PortScannerError('nmap program was not found in path')
nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path'
```

so I looked into file **"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nmap/nmap.py"**. The code where they are checking for *nmap* is not working for some reason.

code:

```
# regex used to detect nmap
    regex = re.compile('Nmap version [0-9]*\.[0-9]*[^ ]* \( http://nmap\.org \)')
    # launch 'nmap -V', we wait after 'Nmap version 5.0 ( http://nmap.org )'
    p = subprocess.Popen(['nmap', '-V'], bufsize=10000, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    self._nmap_last_output = p.communicate()[0] # store stdout
    for line in self._nmap_last_output.split('\n'):
        if regex.match(line) is not None:
            is_nmap_found = True
            # Search for version number
            regex_version = re.compile('[0-9]+')
            regex_subversion = re.compile('\.[0-9]+')

            rv = regex_version.search(line)
            rsv = regex_subversion.search(line)

            if rv is not None and rsv is not None:
                # extract version/subversion
                self._nmap_version_number = int(line[rv.start():rv.end()])
                self._nmap_subversion_number = int(line[rsv.start()+1:rsv.end()])
            break

    if is_nmap_found == False:
        raise PortScannerError('nmap program was not found in path')
```

I found out that first **regex** is not working so I changed this:

from :

```
regex = re.compile('Nmap version [0-9]*\.[0-9]*[^ ]* \( http://nmap\.org \)')
```

to:

```
regex = re.compile('Nmap version [0-9]*\.[0-9]*)
```

Now it is working just like it suppose to work!